# form_tag doesn't work

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am a bit new to rails and I have the following code:

```
  <% form_tag "/producers/#{@user.id}", method: :get do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```

It doesn't do anything. Replaced it with

```
  <form action="/producers/<%= @user.id %>" method="get">
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
    </p>
  </form>
```

and all is fine. I know I should do producer_path(@user) but I am trying to find out what's wrong.

What am I missing?

Comment: Define "doesn't do anything". What's rendered?

Comment: nothing. there is a blank. no code is generated in the html source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the line

`<% form_tag %>`

**this won't print anything to the page**

`<%= %>`

is the ERB tag for when you want to print things

```
<%= 'hello' %>
```

prints hello

```
<% 'hello' %>
```

merely evaluates it

Comment: thx. that's what happens if you stare at a piece of code for an hour straight, you miss the obvious.